# Aligning an UnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: ios, swift

Apple docs for UnsafeMutablePointer say that the pointer should be aligned:

> The pointer should be aligned to alignof(Memory.self).

I understand that the CPU accesses memory more efficiently with aligned pointers and always reads as many bytes at once as its word size is. But I don't understand what is `Memory.self` and how to align my allocated `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>` buffer? If I have a 64-bit processor, should I pad all values to 8 bytes or use `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int64>` and always write 8-byte values?

Comment: The alignment of `Int8` is *one*, so there is not need to align an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`. But generally, any pointer obtained by `.alloc()` will be properly aligned. You don't have to worry about it unless you do your own pointer arithmetic or convert between pointers of different types.

Comment: How much better is the performance if I use <Int64> instead of <Int8> and try to combine data to 8-byte chunks? I mean combining the values takes time too.

Comment: That depends on what you are doing  with the values, there is no "one fits all" answer to this question.

Comment: @Tapani: You find out by _measuring_. Measure how long your code takes one way, and how long it takes another way, and find the difference. If measuring is too much work then you don't worry about the performance.

Comment: @gnasher729: yes you are right. Maybe I just write two different implementations and see if there is any difference in the performance.